# shell unexpected behaviour when renaming a file with underscore in filename

Tags: shell

This command will generate ten files as expected:

```
for i in `seq 10`; do touch model; mv model model_$i; done
```

However, this one will only generate a file called "model_":

```
for i in `seq 10`; do touch model_best; mv model_best model_$i_best; done
```

It seems that the underscore in the filename has some influence, but what actually happens? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3):

In your second example, `$i_best` is being interpreted as a variable name, and presumably expanding to an empty string.

Use curly braces and/or quotes to expand `$i`:

```
for i in `seq 10`; do 
    touch model_best     

    # just quote the variable (my favourite)
    mv model_best model_"$i"_best      

    # or (belt and braces approach, quotes can also go around the whole arg)
    # mv model_best model_"${i}"_best

    # or just curly braces
    # fine here since $i contains no spaces or glob characters 
    # (but I don't like it)
    # mv model_best model_${i}_best
done
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.